# Arms get tight and being during workout

Tags: weightlifting, workout, health

Basically what the title says. I just started working out for about a month now and my arms get veiny even when I'm not doing an arm workout, they also feel tight and I don't have much energy to use them, even though my muscles feel fine. Is this normal? Or should I be worried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having veins push up towards the skin layer is one of the bodies ways of trying to say you need more oxygen.

Muscles feeling tight when not doing much especially after only about a month of working out is most likely due to not stretching enough. You should increase the amount of times you stretch or increase the duration.

I normally stretch a bit in the morning after waking up. Then before a workout and then after the workout is over.

Here is a small [blog](https://www.bettermovement.org/blog/2015/why-do-muscles-feel-tight) that will help you to understand muscle tightness a little better. And help narrow down your actual problem.

Having not enough energy could be a ton of things. Try to get some vitamin b supplements or energy drinks. You may also not have enough of potassium in your system. Try a banana. If it continues or gets worse I would see a doctor as they can tell you a lot more. You can look up some of the reasons on fatigue [here](http://www.mayoclinic.org/symptoms/fatigue/basics/causes/sym-20050894). There are many other articles that can help you out.

If it is just a small muscle area that feels weak then you may be over-working that muscle group.

Comment: Your answer seems to be a tad on the speculative side.  It would help if you could provide some facts/science to back up your comments.

Comment: @rrirower I updated it a little to add a few more details / articles to narrow down the problem / solution.